# Updating EditText automatically

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have three edittext in activity,

```
[Edit text 1] -->e1
[Edit text 2] -->e2
[Edit text 3] -->e3
```

If  i write some value in e1 and e2 the result should show in e3, and if write values in e2 and e3 result should be in e1 and in same way if i write values in e1 and e3 result should be in e2, how can i do this?

Edit:

```
e1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(e2.getText().toString().length()>0)
            {
            getLvalue();
            }else if(e3.getText().toString().length()>0){
                getDvalue();
            }
        }
    });
```

in the same way other two..

Comment: `how can i do this?` by writing code.

Comment: then write and post :P @InnocentKiller

Comment: First show us what have you written then we will post.

Comment: Yes, check now.. I posted

Comment: @PandiriDeepak, check my answer. And update me still if you have any problem, i will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Okay great Try something like this,

```
EditText e1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
EditText e2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
EditText e3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
```

Now in button click event check which one is empty and which one is filled with data so

```
submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
         if (e3.getText.toString().trim() == "")
         {
             e3.setText(e1 + e2);
         }else if (e2.getText.toString().trim() == ""){
             e2.setText(e1 + e3);
         }else if (e1.getText.toString().trim() == ""){
             e1.setText(e1 + e2);
         }else {
           // Set alert dialog saying all three edit-text is empty
         }
        }
    });
```

Hope this will help you. Happy Coding...

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but here i dont want to use any button's to press submit.

Comment: @PandiriDeepak, also you can set this condition's inside `e1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()` just modify the content.

Comment: Create changelistner for all three edit-text and use this code inside all.